# List Limit Override

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, contact

Joomla 3.6.5

I have a menu item type *Contacts » List Contacts in a Category*. I have 150+ contacts.

I would like to override the default list limit on **this page only**.

Currently when the contact page loads it shows 25 contacts, which is the limit set in my Joomla global config. Is there any way I can change this so the complete list of 150+ loads?

I have created a template override in `/html/com_contact/category/default_items.php`.

Thanks

Comment: The $items are loaded in the model. So you can't change the amount in the tmpl override.
I think you will need to write a plugin to get that working.

Comment: The answer at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/3810/120 might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is very helpful and solved my issue.

To override, Joomla components generally seem to use this in the model: Using $limit = 0 shows all items

```
protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
{
    // set limit
    $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);
    // set start (eg. what record to begin pagination at)
    $this->setState('list.start', $value);
}
```

[How to set get('Items') limit?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/3808/how-to-set-getitems-limit/3810#3810)